# Extract an XML file (TED Europe) to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an XML from TED Europe (like this:[TED Europa XML Files (Login required)](http://ted.europa.eu/TED/misc/xmlPackagesDownload.do)) Within the XML Files are public procurement contracts.

My question is now how can I parse the XML File to a pandas dataframe.
So far I tried to achieve this using the ElementTree package.

However since I am still a beginner habe trouble extracting the information since the relevant text is marked with only "p" tags.

How can I extract this information for the english translation so that for example "TI_MARK" is the column header and the information within "TXT_MARK" and the "p" tags are the rows? The other rows are later filled with information from other public procurement XML Files.

```xml
<FORM_SECTION>
  <OTH_NOT LG="DA" VERSION="R2.0.8.S03.E01" CATEGORY="TRANSLATION">
  <OTH_NOT LG="DE" VERSION="R2.0.8.S03.E01" CATEGORY="TRANSLATION">
  <OTH_NOT LG="EN" VERSION="R2.0.8.S03.E01" CATEGORY="ORIGINAL">
        <FD_OTH_NOT>
          <TI_DOC>
            <P>BE-Brussels: IPA - Improved implementation of animal health, food safety and phytosanitary legislation and corresponding information systems</P>
          </TI_DOC>
          <STI_DOC>
            <P>Location — The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</P>
          </STI_DOC>
          <STI_DOC>
            <P>SERVICE CONTRACT NOTICE</P>
          </STI_DOC>
          <CONTENTS>
            <GR_SEQ>
              <TI_GRSEQ>
                <BLK_BTX/>
              </TI_GRSEQ>
              <BLK_BTX_SEQ>
                <MARK_LIST>
                  <MLI_OCCUR NO_SEQ="001">
                    <NO_MARK>1.</NO_MARK>
                    <TI_MARK>Publication reference</TI_MARK>
                    <TXT_MARK>
                      <P>EuropeAid/139253/DH/SER/MK</P>
                    </TXT_MARK>
                  </MLI_OCCUR>
                  <MLI_OCCUR NO_SEQ="002">
                    <NO_MARK>2.</NO_MARK>
                    <TI_MARK>Procedure</TI_MARK>
                    <TXT_MARK>
                      <P>Restricted</P>
                    </TXT_MARK>
                  </MLI_OCCUR>
```

So far my code is:

```python
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('196658_2018.xml')

#Print Tree
print(tree)

#tree=ET.ElementTree(file='196658_2018.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#Print root
print(root)

for element in root.findall('{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}FORM_SECTION/{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}OTH_NOT/{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}FD_OTH_NOT/{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}TI_DOC/{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}P'):

    print(element.text)
```

Strangely the extraction only works if I add {ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication} to each path element.

Moving on from that I have problems writing a function which contains all paths with infos and appends them to a pandas dataframe. Ideally only the english translation should be extracted.

For another part of the XML File I used a function like this:

```python
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse_xml_fields(file, base_tag, tag_list, final_list):
    root = etree.parse(file)
    nodes = root.findall("//{}".format(base_tag))
    for node in nodes:
        item = {}
        for tag in tag_list:
            if node.find(".//{}".format(tag)) is not None:
                item[tag] = node.find(".//{}".format(tag)).text.strip()
        final_list.append(item)

# My variables
field_list = ["{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}TI_CY","{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}TI_TOWN", "{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}TI_TEXT"]
entities_list = []

parse_xml_fields("196658_2018.xml", "{ted/R2.0.8.S03/publication}ML_TI_DOC", field_list, entities_list)


df = pd.DataFrame(entities_list, columns=field_list)
print(df)

#better column names
df.columns = ['Country', 'Town', 'Text']

df.to_csv("TED_Europa_List.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

The Path and Tags however are much more distinguishable for this section because the tags already are named after their content and the tags are more distinguishable.